# How to convert the data from MongoDB to the View through the Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In Application.java, I have read each document in a collection from a MongoDB database. And I stored all these documents in an ArrayList. I am wondering how to pass this ArrayList to the Controller class?

This is a Spring Boot web application. And I am using Spring MVC to work on this project.

### This class is the Application.java. I fetched all the shoes from MongoDB and stored them in the list variable.

```
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ShoeRepository repository;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        // fetch all shoes
        List<Shoe> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Shoes found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Shoe shoe : repository.findAll()) {
            //System.out.println(customer);
            list.add(shoe);
        }
        System.out.println("all shoes have been saved to the list");
    }
}
```

This class is my Controller class:

---

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=true) List<Shoe> list, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", list.get(0).asin);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

Who can tell me how to pass the list variable in the Application class to the Controller class? I want to visualize the data stored in the list variable in the View.

Comment: life is busy, but have you tried reading: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: @emotionlessbananas. Yes I have read it, but it only shows me how to read the data in Application.java. I am wondeing how to pass these data to the Controller and View if I fetch the data in Application.java? I am wondering how to read the data in a method in Controller class? Can you answer my questions?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the main point here. A controller class is different from a main application class in spring-boot. The controller class is used to serve the http request according to the path. Each request is served by a different thread. The springboot follows the MVC architecture for this.So, you should have a Controller class to serve the request , a Service class to create the model and a Repository layer to access the database whichever it may be. And also the Model class is returned from the controller.

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private ShoeRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=true) List<Shoe> list, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", list.get(0).asin);
        List<Shoe> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(repository.findAll());
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

You could call the repository method from the controller to access the data which should be the right way to go ,or better yet , have a service class in between if you have more logic to be implemented.

```
public interface ShoeRepository extends MongoRepository<Shoe, Long> {

    //Custom Query
    @Query("SELECT o FROM Object o WHERE o.field = somethingThatValidsIt")
    public List<Shoe> customFindAll();

    //Default CRUD repository implementation
    public List<Shoe> findAll()

    //Other methods
    public Shoe findByNameAndAvailable(String name, boolean available);

}
```

Comment: Hello, I already created the Model class and the repository class. public class Shoe {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String asin;
    public String name;
    public String url;
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> colorSizes = new HashMap<>();
    public HashMap<String, String> colorPrice = new HashMap<>();

    }public interface ShoeRepository extends MongoRepository<Shoe, String> {

    //public Customer findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Shoe> findByASIN(String ASIN);

} Can you tell me what should I do next?

Comment: You can add the list to the model object then and it will be available at the ui side.

Comment: @ Ananthapadmanabhan, this is my controller class.@Controller
public class GreetingController  {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        ShoeRepository repository = null;
        List<Shoe> list = repository.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("name", list.get(0).asin);
        return "greeting";
    }
} After this project starts running and I opened 'localhost:8080/greeting/', I saw 'Whitelabel Error Page'. Can you tell me how to write the code correctly

Comment: @EricWen can you be more specific about your requirement. I am confused about your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already created a Model class, it is called Shoe. I also have created a ShoeRepository class, which extends from MongoRespository. I hope you can tell me the exact code I need to write in order to fetch all the documents in a collection in a MongoDB database. I plan to use an ArrayList<Shoe> to store all the documents. I hope you can help me with this requirement.

Comment: If you are using spring-data-mongo you could have a repository interface like the one i just updated in the answer and it should work.

Comment: I am wondering how to read the data in a method in Controller class? Can you answer my question?

Comment: You cannot call the method that you wrote in main application from a controller class, you will have to follow the architecture standards and do it like i explained. If you have a spring managed bean it is possible to autowire it and call the method but in your case , you have the method in main application class .

Comment: I have removed the method that I have wriiten in main application. I am wondering how to write the exact code in Controller class so that I can fetch the data from MongoDB?

Comment: Hello! I tried to pass a string from the Controller to the View. The string is a image url, and I tried to show that image again by using <img src= ${image}> This line of code is in View. But it does not work. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try using <img src= "${image}"> , if you are returning image from controller. How are you passing the string from controller? Please ask a new question with relevant details if it didn't work for you. Also,mark this question as resolved if you have your code working now.